# Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting mongo error below are the my aggregation.i tried without cursor and it is giving me the
error is like The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument. after
addind the cursor it is giving me the different error like Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var matches = mongoose.model('matches');
var userjoinings = mongoose.model('userjoinings');

 module.exports = (function(){
return{
   getAllUpcomingMatches:function(request,response){
   var arr = new Array();
        
        arr.push({$match:{username:request.body.username,mobilenumber:request.body.mobilenumber}})
        arr.push( {$lookup:{ from: userjoinings,localField: 'matchId', foreignField: "matchId", as: "match_data"}})
        arr.push({$match:{match_data:[]}})

          matches.aggregate(arr,{"allowDiskUse":true},{cursor:{batchSize: 1000}},function(result){
            if(result){
               response.json(result)
            } else {
              response.send(error)
            }
                     
         })
      }
   })
```

kindly help me.

Comment: i tried like this below   p.match( {username:request.body.username,mobilen umber:request.body.mobilenumber})   ,  p.lookup({ from: userjoinings,localField: 'matchId', foreignField: "matchId", as: "match_data"}) ,    p.match({match_data:[]}),  promise = p.cursor({ batchSize: 1000 }).exec()
            promise.then(function(result){
                console.log(result)
            })

Comment: giving error promise.then not working

Comment: i have updated  the question. matches is collection

Comment: yes i have defined it. it is there in separate folder like models.

Comment: var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var matchSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
        {
            "teamA": {type: String, required: true},
            "username":{type: String, required: true},
            "matchId":{type: String, required: true},
            "matchTitle":{type:String,required: true}, 
            "teamALogo":{type:String,required: true},  }
);
mongoose.model('matches',matchSchema); this is my schema

Comment: Sorry i can't help you because there are lot of incomplete information in your question, like missing schema for `userjoinings` , you are matching `mobilenumber` but its not available in `match` schema, and my suggestion is to check proper documentation its easy and quick implementation.

Comment: i can not display all the information here. both schemas are  very big. all things are working for me in project except this. that fine i will try . thanks